Adjusting PlaneGeometry Dimensions and Camera Distance to Fill Screen width or height Without Exceeding Boundaries
I am trying  calculate the camera distance so that it fills the entire screen width or height without exceeding the screen boundaries.
Requirements

Get the width and height of renderer.domElement.

Calculate the camera distance so that the PlaneGeometry fills the entire screen width or height  without exceeding the screen boundaries.


Expected Result

The PlaneGeometry width or height  should match those of renderer.domElement.

The camera distance should be calculated appropriately so that the PlaneGeometry fills the entire screen width or height  without exceeding the screen boundaries.


Code Example
import * as THREE from 'three';

// Create scene, camera, and renderer
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Get the width and height of renderer.domElement
const screenWidth = renderer.domElement.clientWidth;
const screenHeight = renderer.domElement.clientHeight;

// Create PlaneGeometry
const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 30);// The width and height are not fixed and cannot be changed
const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
const planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
scene.add(planeMesh);

// `PlaneGeometry` 的宽度和高度
const planeWidth = planeGeometry.parameters.width;
const planeHeight = planeGeometry.parameters.height;

// Camera field of view (vertical)
const fovRadians = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(camera.fov);

// Calculate camera distance
function calculateCameraDistance(screenWidth: number, screenHeight: number, planeWidth: number, planeHeight: number): number {
    const planeAspectRatio = planeWidth / planeHeight;
    const screenAspectRatio = screenWidth / screenHeight;

    if (planeAspectRatio > screenAspectRatio) {
        // Width fills screen width
        return (planeWidth / 2) / (Math.tan(fovRadians / 2) * (screenWidth / (2 * screenHeight)));
    } else {
        // Height fills screen height
        return planeHeight / (2 * Math.tan(fovRadians / 2));
    }
}

// Calculate camera distance
const cameraDistance = calculateCameraDistance(screenWidth, screenHeight, planeWidth , planeHeight );

// Set camera position
camera.position.z = cameraDistance;

console.log(`Camera Distance: ${cameraDistance}`);

// Render scene
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();

Question
How can I ensure that the PlaneGeometry dimensions match screen width or height and calculate the appropriate camera distance so that the PlaneGeometry fills the entire screen without exceeding the screen boundaries?

It is easier if you use an orthographic camera, instead. https://jsfiddle.net/gphuf8do/

What effect are you trying to produce by having this viewport-matching flat-to-screen plane? Are you using it for a background color/image/video? Those could just be layered behind the canvas, and the renderer made transparent. Or does it need to interact with the 3D scene somehow?
